Issue in retrieving number from HTML string using regular expression matcher
I'm facing difficulty retrieving a specific text pattern from an HTML element in my webpage. Here's the HTML snippet:
This is from my website and I want to retrieve from "
Work Order 0000037282 has been reissued.

only :
0000037282

Save it and use it later in another page something like workordernumber =
0000037282

<div class="row ng-scope" ng-if="successMessages.length">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <!-- ngRepeat: success in successMessages track by $index -->
            <div class="row ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="success in successMessages track by $index" ng-bind="success.message">Invoice 0000026791 has been credited. Credit document HO0000000033 was created.</div>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: success in successMessages track by $index -->
            <div class="row ng-binding ng-scope" ng-repeat="success in successMessages track by $index" ng-bind="success.message">Work Order 0000037282 has been reissued.</div>
            <!-- end ngRepeat: success in successMessages track by $index -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

This is what i tried till now and with 0 success :
this is from my test
await reissueWorkOrderConfirmationModal.ConfirmAsync();

string? workOrderNumber = await creditInvoiceModal.GetReissuedWorkOrderNumberAsync();

if (workOrderNumber != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Reissued Work Order Number: {workOrderNumber}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to retrieve the reissued work order number.");
}

And this is what i added in the modal :
public async Task<string?> GetReissuedWorkOrderNumberAsync()
{
    // Execute JavaScript in the browser context to retrieve the text of the success message elements
    string successMessages = await _page.EvaluateAsync<string>(@"() => {
        const messages = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.alert.alert-success .row.ng-binding.ng-scope'));
        return messages.map(message => message.innerText).join('|');
    }");
    // Define the regular expression pattern to match the Work Order number
    string pattern = @"Work Order (\d+) has been reissued.";
    // Use regular expression to match the pattern
    Match match = Regex.Match(successMessages, pattern);
    // Check if the pattern is found
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // Extract the Work Order number from the matched groups
        string workOrderNumber = match.Groups[1].Value;
        return workOrderNumber;
    }
    // Return null if the pattern is not found
    return null;
}


The Groups collection of the match object is to be iterated differently, have you seen the example code in the documentation? here

hmm i looked over and will see how can i adapt my code :(
i only got to get the invoice text

The pattern seems quite ok, you just might want to escape the trailing dot: \..
As you are defining a capture group in your regex, you should iterate over captures:
Match match = Regex.Match(successMessages, pattern);
if (match.Success)
{
   var captures = match.Groups[2].Captures;

   var invoiceId = captures.FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
}


Hi , sadly it doesn't work  :( i think i got once to get this message : Invoice 0000026791 has been credited. Credit document HO0000000033 was created.
to give a little context , you first get the first message , after you click another button and it will generate the work order again.
And i need to extract from here :
Work Order 0000037282 has been reissued.
i need the number , which will be different each time i run the automation test
